# Could not instantiate controllers.WebJarAssets during testing

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, specs2

Play is working fine when I am using `sbt run`. However, when I am trying to do such test:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MarketApiSpec extends Specification {
  "Market API" should {
    "load product list" in new WithApplication {
      val completed = route(FakeRequest("GET", "/api/products")).get.map(x => Json.parse(x.body.toString()))
      val jsonObject = Await.result(completed, Duration("1s"))
      jsonObject.get("products").get(0).get("name").asText() must beEqualTo("Programmer");
    }
  }
}
```

By a `sbt test` I get such error exception:

```
[info] Market API should
[info] ! load product list
[error]    RuntimeException: : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class controllers.WebJarAssets$  (Action.scala:523)
[error] play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:523)
```

I googled a lot, however I didn't find the solution. I think its related to sbt somehow, but even giving a test scope doesn't help.